# Automapper, can we see how it maps objects?

Tags: c#, automapper

Quick newbie question about Automapper.

I have the following code:

```
CreateMap<MyDataContract, MyViewModel>()
    .MapFrom(s => s.Trans, d => d.Trans);
```

In the DataContract, MyDataContract, I have the following:

```
[DataMember]
public IEnumerable<ReferTypeDataContract> Refer { get; set;}
```

I am trying to find out how Automapper is mapping this from the above CreateMap to the ReferTypeDataContract. Is there any visual tools to examine this, or some debug code that can be added to make this visible.

The reason I ask, is that I have a different mapping that is mapping the MyDataContract, but I am getting a different set of results for the Refer list and cannot figure this out.

Comment: Post your code then. Automapper maps fields by name. You didn't post anything that shows usage of `Refer`

Comment: Here is the [Source](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), the rest is up to you.

Comment: So in this case, it is just a black box that does it own thing

Comment: It is a library that does its own thing, yes.  Libraries tend to do that.  What did you think it was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Automapper can visualize its execution plan as described in docs: [Understanding your mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Understanding-your-mapping).

It means you can get the expression tree for any source-target pair. For example:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {/* your mappings */});

LambdaExpression executionPlan = configuration.BuildExecutionPlan(typeof(Foo), typeof(Bar));
```

Documentation offers to use this [VS extention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) to visualize the tree. In case it doesn't work, let's use the built-in text visualizer. Start with a source class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<FooInner> Inners { get; set; }
}
```

Create a map configuration `Foo -> Bar`, `FooInner -> BarInner`. Set a breakpoint after `BuildExecutionPlan` method is called and examine `executionPlan` in Quick Watch (`Shift+F9`). Then go to `DebugView` property and select `Text visualizer` arrow to open it in a new window. Usually, you get a lot of text with statements like below:

```
$resolvedValue = .If (
    False || $src == null
) {
    .Default(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XUnitTests.FooInner])
} .Else {
    $src.Inners
};

$passedDestination = .If ($dest == null) {
    .Default(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[XUnitTests.BarInner])
} .Else {
    $typeMapDestination.Inners
};
```

So it describes in detail how `Foo` properties are mapped.